# blazor wasm deployment - Where is the run time of .net 6.0 copied to the folder when it is publised as self contained azure app service

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

[image]

This is my blazor publish (wasm+hosted) properties, I am deploying it as a self contained application which I am assuming means the .net run time 6.0 also will be packaged to it. Now I deploy it to azure portal. Where do I see the .net run time installed?

[image]

This is the Kudu diagnostic console of my azure app service. I browsed all folders, I am not able to see where it is installed. Can any one help?

Comment: dll files are always placed in `site\wwwroot`, if you couldn't find them, then it might be related with azure web app

Answer (score 0):

I have a test with blazor server application to publish both with self-contained mode and framework dependent mode. I published it to folder and here is it.

[image]

As we can see when we published as self-contained mode, we will have `coreclr.dll`. And after we followed the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-the-app-self-contained) to deploy the app self-contained, we should be able to have the dll in `\site\wwwroot`

[image]

I have a test in my side and :

[image]

Comment: just 4Mb? the whole .net core is so small? is that it? I forgot to mention that the blazor application was wasm hosted.

Comment: I didn't investigate corecli.dll before, so when you ask `where is the .net runtime`, I start testing in my side to do a self-contained publishment, and checking all the generated files, then I order by all the files, and this one looks like the target, so I searched for this file name, and google told me this is the .net runtime.

Comment: does it mean when it is deployed as self hosted (wasm)and the client access the url through browser i assume the .net core 6 framework also get deployed and I assume it will atleast some 100MB? pls correct me if I am wrong

Comment: basically, when we choose azure web app as the hosting platform, we already have default runtime installed, you can see them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk>` in kudo, so I'm not very sure why you need to publish the app as self contained to azure web app. Then I try to download coreclr.dll separately, and I found it looks like only have 5Mb https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/coreclr

Comment: I'm not sure how big in size of the runtime, but I know runtime is different from the SDK